# SublimeText3 Color Highlighter stopped working

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Turned on laptop today and ColorHighlighter plugin stopped working.
I have deleted and re-installed the package multiple times and still nothing.

When i click on tools -> Color Highlighter, the options Highlight Style and Highlight all styles have a '>' to click to the next menu but when I click them they don't do anything.

Anyone experienced this or know how to fix?

Comment: According to its [Package Control page](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Color%20Highlighter), it was just updated a day or so ago, so there's probably been some error introduced. Go [here](https://github.com/Monnoroch/ColorHighlighter/issues) to open a new issue. Before you do, open the console (Ctrl+`) and copy the full text of any errors that appear on startup or when trying to use one of the functions. Also include your operating system and the exact build number of Sublime you're using.

Comment: Have you installed the control package?

Comment: Thanks @MattDMo i just saw there was an update, i'll post the issue there.

Comment: Yes it's installed @Grald